# Xcode 5 LLVM printf with %s format specifier not working in debug console

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, llvm

Here is the problem

I am reviving some old code (pre-ARC, Xcode 4, GDB) in Xcode 5 and while everything compiles and starts fine I have a problem with the output log of the debugger when printing the contents of a C++ string object.

```
#define DebugPrintf(args...) x_Printf(__FILE__,__LINE__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,args);

void x_Printf(const char *file, int lineNumber, const char *funcName, const char *format,...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start (ap, format);
    printf("%s (%s:%d)",funcName,file,lineNumber);
    printf(format,ap);
    va_end (ap);
}


void MyFunc() 
{
    string name;

    …

    DebugPrintf("Loaded entity %s\n",name.c_str());
}
```

Results in:

```
void MyFunc() (File.cpp:52)Loaded entity \373*
${\370\325\377\277:{\373*
Ģ\247\300\242\247`6*
```

However inspecting the name C++ string object shows me that it clearly contains "MainMenu" as content.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: I would suggest that your title, accusing printf of failing to use %s correctly, is in fact wrong. What happens if you replace `name.c_str()` with `"test"`? What happens if you replace `DebugPrintf` in the call with `printf`? You need to do more to prove the root cause before assuming what you have. Edit: or use vprintf instead of printf, as @BryanChen was keen enough to observe :)

Comment: Well, you can always suggest a better title, but I didn't find any that was reasonably short. I just wrote down what I saw, namely that %s didn't do what it used to do in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [vprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vprintf/)

```
void x_Printf(const char *file, int lineNumber, const char *funcName, const char *format,...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start (ap, format);
    printf("%s (%s:%d)",funcName,file,lineNumber);
    vprintf(format,ap); // <-- vprintf
    va_end (ap);
}
```